# Proper Schema.org type for generic webpage on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, schema.org

I installed one of the most popular Schema.org mark-up plugins on WordPress ([WP SEO Structured Data Schema](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-seo-structured-data-schema/)) to resolve my Google Console errors.

For blog posts it is pretty straight forward, but I also have generic pages like 'about me' or 'our mission'. What type is best suited for these? `Service`?

As far as I can tell, I can only choose those options:

[image: Form that allows to select one of these types: Article, Blog Posting, News Article, Event, Product, Video, Service, Review, Aggregate Ratings]

Comment: It sounds like you want to use schema just for the sake of using it.   No schema at all is just fine in this case.